# Fanatic badge time question

Tags: discussion, badges

I have a quick question about the time the days are counted in Fanatic badge. Do I understand correctly that badge will reset on the new UTC day?

I have 96 days, and I'm leaving Friday morning for the entire day (I'll visit website in the morning before I leave), and I only will be able to return saturday evening 10pm pst (live in califirnia). If I enter the website around 10pm pst in scenario I just desccribed, will it still count into my badge, or will it be reset at that point? I just REALLY don't want to lose my progress of 96 days and start from scratch again =(

Comment: @yellowantphil It is, so, given the scenario above, will I still be safe to have a time gap between friday morning and saturday 10pm pst in order not to lose my progress?

Comment: @yellowantphil Seriously??? That would suck so bad >_<

Comment: @yellowantphil Worst case scenario would be between 9am PST fridat and 10pm pst saturday.

Comment: @yellowantphil Yeah, I normally go through some questions and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: If you used the mobile app to vote on content or even answer, your time would be counted and you could eschew this scenario.  Unless, that is, you're going to a place with no mobile network reception...

Comment: @Makoto I did try going to SO through my mobile, logged in and everything. It previously did not count my initial 27 days, so I had to start over again.

Comment: @VadzimSavenok:  You can't just log in to the mobile app; you actually have to *do* stuff on the site through the app for your activity to count.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, hopefully, I can find wireless internet and do some stuff from my tablet. I will report the results on sunday morning =)

Comment: @Makoto Just returned back. Thankfully, I was able to connect to wireless xfinity. And my record is safe now. I'll be getting badge on Monday ^_^

Comment: Update: The app now tracks your progress towards the fanatic badge https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/401911

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge is tracked on UTC time. San Francisco is currently UTC-8.

9a PST on Friday would be 5:00 pm UTC (Friday).

10p PST Saturday would be 6:00 am UTC (Sunday).

So you'll probably miss a day. It's not the end of the world.

Comment: Sigh, I just hate to lose all the progress that I made. That means I'll have to find a PC somewhere on Saturday to sneak a quick peak...

Comment: happened with me once..i was on 86 and boom i missed one day .. as we have diwali festival over here... and now i'm on day 10 :(

Comment: Been there too. Unfortunately using the app doesn't track your progress either.

Comment: Update: The app now tracks your progress towards the fanatic badge https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/401911